# Tokens Null Pointer Exception

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, token

The following code opens up a text file and breaks its contents into tokens using a comma as the delimiter.  I've used code similar to this and it worked fine but for some reason, this is throwing a NullPointerException on the "myItems[counter].name=myTokens[counter];"

```
public static serial[] getSerials(String fName) throws Exception {
    String total = null;
    BufferedReader lineReader = null;
    lineReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fName));
    while ((lineReader.readLine()) != null) {
        total = total + lineReader.readLine() + ",";
    } //end while
    String[] myTokens = total.split(","); /*break the string csv tokens*/
    /*Put together the serial objects*/
    serial mySerials[] = new serial[myTokens.length];
    int counter = 0;
    while (counter < myTokens.length) {
        mySerials[counter].name = myTokens[counter];
        counter++;
        mySerials[counter - 1].onlineISSN = myTokens[counter];
        counter++;
    }
    return mySerials;
} //end getSerials()
```

Comment: Did you tried to initialize total? like String total = ""; And you can use a StringBuilder to 'build' strings.

Comment: You say you are getting the error on the line `myItems[counter].name=myTokens[counter];` -> There is no line like this in your code

Comment: Please use the Java naming convention! Class names begin with capitals.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've initialized the array

```
serial mySerials[] = new serial[myTokens.length];
```

but not its elements

```
mySerials[counter].name // will throw NPE
```

You need to initialize the elements first before accessing their members

```
mySerials[counter] = new serial(/* something possibly */);
```

Answer (score 1):

You've created the array, but not populated it. So `mySerials[counter]` is null - but you're dereferencing it. I think you want something like:

```
mySerials[counter] = new serial(myTokens[counter]);
```

... assuming your `serial` class has an approriate constructor. Or better, to handle both parts:

```
mySerials[counter] = new serial(myTokens[counter], myTokens[counter + 1]);
counter += 2;
```

Note that only every other element of `mySerials` will be populated... why don't you just create a `List<serial>` instead and add items to that?

Also note that the name `serial` violates Java naming conventions for classes. It's worth getting into good habits in terms of naming as early as possible.

Answer (score 0):

You need to instanciate the `Serial` objects in `mySerials`:

```
while (counter < myTokens.length) {     
    mySerials[counter] = new Serial();
    // ...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 while (counter < myTokens.length) {
     mySerials[counter] = new serial();
     mySerials[counter].name = myTokens[counter];
     counter++;
     mySerials[counter - 1].onlineISSN = myTokens[counter];
     counter++;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

problem is with the line:

```
 mySerials[counter].name = myTokens[counter];
```

just immediate top, you have initialized the array of Searil, but there is no element yet

```
serial mySerials[] = new serial[myTokens.length];
```

so when inside loop you are trying to access the `mySerials[0]` will return you `null` as array by default takes the default value and in your case it will be `null`, and any operation you will perform on `null` will give you a `NPE`, to avoid this, you must have values inside your `array` at the time of creation/initialization or just immediate above when you will try to use.